# Hive Explode / Lateral View Table

Tags: hive, hiveql

Table : jd1 (Comaparison Table)

Table : data1 (New Values Table)

I have write this query in sql server it's working but in hive it shows me an error

```
select * from data1;

1   siva    hadoop
1   siva    hive
1   siva    spark
1   siva    hbase
1   siva    mapreduce
1   siva    hdfs
2   kumar   hadoop
2   kumar   hive
2   kumar   python
2   kumar   spark
3   naveen  hive
3   naveen  hadoop
3   naveen  flume
3   naveen  kafka
```

select * from jd1;

```
1   hadoop
1   hive
1   spark
1   hbase
1   mapreduce
1   hdfs
1   python
1   java
```

Expected output

```
1   siva    6   85.71428571428571
2   kumar   4   57.142857142857146
3   naveen  2   28.571428571428573
```

My Query

```
select id, name, count(*), ((count(*)*100)/(select count(skills)from jd1))avg
from (select n.id, n.name, n.skills
      from data1 n join jd1 t on (n.skills=t.skills))a
group by id,name;
```

**Error**

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:44 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'count' '(' in expression specification
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one more table for jd skill as skill_count and join this tables.

```
SELECT n.Id, n.Job_Id, n.Name, n.Email, n.Mobile_Number, n.Education, n.Total_Experiance,((count(n.skills)*100)/s.skill_count) Average
FROM new_resume n
JOIN new_jd t ON n.skills=t.skills
JOIN skill_count s ON n.job_id = s.job_id
GROUP BY n.Id, n.Job_Id, n.Name, n.Email, n.Mobile_Number, n.Education, n.Total_Experiance,s.skill_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, name, count(*) cnt, count(*)*100/skill_cnt cnt_pct
from (select n.id, n.name, n.skills, t.skill_cnt 
      from data1 n 
           inner join (select skills, count(*) over() skill_cnt from jd1) t 
                      on n.skills=t.skills
     ) a
group by id,name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT n.id, n.name, COUNT(n.skills), COUNT(n.skills)/skill_cnt.total_skill
FROM data1 n
JOIN jd1 t ON n.skills=t.skills
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) total_skill FROM jd1) skill_cnt
GROUP BY n.id, n.name, total_skill
```

Comment: It show this error  FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 3:32 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'TOTAL_SKILLS'

Comment: @Siva, Try now.

Comment: @ Ankit Bajpai.FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 6:23 Invalid table alias or column reference 'TOTAL_SKILLS': (possible column names are: n.id, n.name, n.skills, t.id, t.skills)

Comment: @ Ankit Bajpai. FAILED: ParseException line 1:42 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'COUNT' '(' in expression specification

Comment: May you give it a try now?